# Cannot put one div under the other with z-index

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I want to get a "retro effect" to my calculator, sort of like a stairs effect on the edges of it. The only way i imagined it could work is with 2 divs under it, one longer and thinner than the actual calculator and the other one wider and shorter. I managed (somehow, thank god) to put one div where i want it, but it is still above the calculator. Can someone enlghten me on what i am doing wrong, please?

Here are the html, css (with bootstrap 3) and:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: antiquewhite;
  1font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  1font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
}

#calc {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: #abc6c2;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #224662;
  height: 450px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

#afis {
  width: 310px;
  background: #bcbcbc;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

#result p {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#keyboard {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn {
  padding: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.input {
  border-radius: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.umbrasus {
  text-align: center;
  width: 360px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: #abc6c2;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: red;
  height: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h3>Javascript Calculator</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="calc">
    <div class="umbrasus"></div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <input class="display" type="text" name="Display" id="afis">
    </div>
    <div id="keyboard">

      <div class="row">
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="operator" type="button" value="+">+</button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="operator" type="button" value="-">-</button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="number" type="button" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="operator" type="button" value="*">*</button>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <button class="clear-btn btn " type="button" value="C">C</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn  " data-role="number" type="button" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="calculate-btn btn " type="button" value="=">=</button>
        <button class="calc-btn btn " data-role="operator" type="button" value="/">/</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: remove `z-index: 99;` ?

Comment: well, that was easy. i thought i tried that. Thank you!

Comment: is there any other way to make this work, btw?

Comment: what was the issue of the first way? you cannot remove the z-index:99?

Comment: none, i was just curious if i could get the effect i wanted in any other way